# KissXml on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml

I have dowload a KissXml project.
I must add all the files to my project (excluding DDXMLTesting).
Sorry for the stupid question but i must insert all class in the classes folder (http://ixhan.com/2010/03/tutorial-of-kissxml-iphone/) or i can do another operation.
Sorry but i'm a beginner programmer for iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to import all the classes in new group in your project when you are doing it with sdk.

Answer (score 0):

yes, otherwise it will not compile/link/run

Answer (score 0):

The "getting started"-section of the original source home page contains the best information to get it up and running. Just follow the steps exactly as they're described there and you should be ready to go in 5 minutes.

http://code.google.com/p/kissxml/wiki/GettingStarted